# How to Create New Custom Product Details Page In NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

How to create new custom product details page in NopCommerce new generic url RouteProvice and new HTML page

Answer (score 1):

Just write Generic route url in plugin and update order, give your own generic route name.

Register Generic router at DependencyRegister.

Update your controller and actionMethod for product detail page.

Comment: Review this post

https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/49803/nop-39-override-urlrouteurlcategory-new-sename-categorysename-.aspx